# Reloaddata not call cellForRowatIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I create a UITableViewController using **storyboard**, and want to reload the tableview every time it detect a device(for bonjour protocol).
  However, the reload data method only calls numberofRows, but not call CellForRowatIndexPath. So I have nothing changed. The mutablearray I checked is always going correctly. NewObjects are added. But the tableview doesn't change with the array. So I am wondering if I set sth wrong here.

From the NSLog I added, I found, I could load the tableview at the beginning with 
the initialized array

```
 self.serviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test", nil];
```

But in the method

```
 - (void)addService:(NSNetService *)....
```

Everytime I reload, the new object can be added to the mutableArray, but the tableview doesn't change with the array. (It called the numberOfRows, and I check the array size returned is not 0, but then it doesn't call the cellOfRowAtIndex)

Here is my code

.h file

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "Server.h"
   @interface BrowserViewController : UITableViewController <ServerDelegate>
    {
       Server *_server;
       NSMutableArray *_serviceArray;
    }

   @property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *serviceArray;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) Server *server;


   - (void)addService:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more;
   @end
```

.m file

```
   #import "BrowserViewController.h"
   @implementation BrowserViewController
   @synthesize serviceArray = _serviceArray;
   @synthesize server = _server;

   - (void) dealloc
   {
       [self.serviceArray release];
       [self.tableView release];
       [super dealloc];

    }



   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
        self.title = @"Service Browser";


        _serviceArray = nil;
        self.serviceArray = nil;

        [self.tableView setDelegate: self];
        [self.tableView setDataSource:self];  
        //actually I set this in the storyboard already

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        _serviceArray = nil;
        NSLog(@"viewwilldisappear");
    }

    - (NSMutableArray *)serviceArray {

      if(nil == _serviceArray) {
         self.serviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test", nil];
    }
      else
    {
        NSLog(@"update array");
    }

    return _serviceArray;

    }

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


   - (void)addService:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more{

    [self.serviceArray addObject:service];

    if (!more) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
         }
    }

   #pragma mark - Table view data source



  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      return 1;
   }

  - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"Connection Choices";
    }


  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.serviceArray count];

     }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *Cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       if (Cell == nil) {
            Cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        }

       NSString *text = [self.serviceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       Cell.textLabel.text = text;

       return Cell;
       }

       @end
```

I checked some solution, it's either delegate setting problem, or the array is null. or cell initialized without space. Is there any way to check what's the delegate of some method ?

I also tried to create a tableview property in the .h file, linked IBOutlet, then synthesize it in the .m. But still doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

Since a lot of tutorials are based on window-based application, could someone maybe provide me some tutorial using storyboard and using reloadData ? I could check if the Outlets are wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1**
AddService method is called in the appDelegate

appDelegate.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "Server.h"

 @class BrowserViewController;

 @interface iphoneNetworkAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ServerDelegate>
{
    Server *_server;
    UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet BrowserViewController *BrowserVC;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

appDelegate.m

```
#import "iphoneNetworkAppDelegate.h"
#import "BrowserViewController.h"

@implementation iphoneNetworkAppDelegate
@synthesize window;


- (void)dealloc
{
[window release];


[_server release];
_server = nil;
[BrowserVC release];
BrowserVC = nil;
[super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSString *type = @"TestingProtocol";
_server = [[Server alloc] initWithProtocol:type];
_server.delegate = self;
NSError *error = nil;
if(![_server start:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}

BrowserVC = [BrowserViewController alloc];
if (BrowserVC == nil) {
    NSLog(@"need to init");
}
BrowserVC.server = _server;


return YES;
}



#pragma mark Server Delegate Methods

- (void)serverRemoteConnectionComplete:(Server *)server {
NSLog(@"Server Started");

BrowserVC.server = server;

}

- (void)serverStopped:(Server *)server {
NSLog(@"Server stopped");
}

- (void)server:(Server *)server didNotStart:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
NSLog(@"Server did not start %@", errorDict);
}

- (void)server:(Server *)server didAcceptData:(NSData *)data {
NSLog(@"Server did accept data %@", data);

}

- (void)server:(Server *)server lostConnection:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
NSLog(@"Server lost connection %@", errorDict);

}

- (void)serviceAdded:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more {

NSLog(@"service added in delegate");

[BrowserVC addService:service moreComing:more];
}


#pragma mark -

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
[_server stop];
[_server stopBrowser];
}
```

If the appDelegate setting is like this, reloadData cannot be called ?

Comment: Please post the code you actually use, there's no variable `cell` (lower case 'c') defined at the code you posted so it should not even compile.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Cells : %d",[self.serviceArray count]);` in number of rows in section

Comment: @A-Live Thanks for pointing out. Before I tried to comment these line "if(Cell == nil){...}" Since someone told me it's already allocated if I added them in the storyboard. But with or without it...it shows the same result.

Comment: @MidhunMP it changes every time it calls numberOfRowInSection

Comment: @user2152814: are you sure that the cellForRowAtIndexPath is not executing ? Put a NSLog or breakpoint inside that method

Comment: @MidhunMP yes. that's really strange. I put nslog in numberofRows and cellForRowatIndexPath, then it shows...only the numberOfRows called when reloadData. That's why I am so puzzled.

Comment: Please check your delegate and datasource setup, you can access them via `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of `UITableView` outlet. You can either check the values using breakpoints or by logging their description (e.g. `NSLog(@"Delegate %@", [self.tableView.delegate description];`).

Comment: @A-Live in xib I know the delegate and dataSource should be the File's Owner. Since I did it in storyboard, so it should be the TableViewController, right ? Delegate <BrowserViewController: 0x76439a0>

Comment: @user2152814: change `@interface BrowserViewController : UITableViewController <ServerDelegate>` to `@interface BrowserViewController : UITableViewController <ServerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`

Comment: @MidhunMP I tried...I also try to change it in appDelegate...but still..totally desparate

Comment: Sorry if silly question: Did you tried commenting out the bonjour part of the code, and test the adding manually? (add one object to array and call reload)

Comment: @Peteee24 Yes, maybe you're right. In the appDelegate.m , I called one method in the TableViewController and then ask to its tableview to reload...maybe there's some problem there.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this terms may help you:**

1. `self.tableView` is object bind in TableView in XIB.
2. Included `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>` delegates in .h file?
3. Properly set getter setter your object "`self.tableView`"
4. Delegate set?

   a)`[self.tableView setDelegate: self];`

   b)`[self.tableView setDataSource:self];`

Comment: Is it need to set Delegate and DataSource to TableViewController? When we create xib, I think its automatically  get wired . Please confirm . Is it necessary to set property to `tableView` for tableViewController?

Comment: Yes you have to bind self.tableview to TableViewController when u create  xib.

Comment: Not really automatically.. at least you have to drag&drop your table view to your controller. Make sure it really is the controller and not the main view.

Comment: @John No, When you create UITableViewController xib with TableViewController class, Controller have variable tableView itself. If you create tableView in sense , you have wire up. But In tableview controller , it's not needed.

Comment: @MarcMosby Yes you have to drag and drop you tableView to your controller if you have UIViewController, but if you have UITableViewController, so tableview already wire up to your view . Check your files owner after creating TableviewController.

Answer (score 0):

1. i think No need for the following lines in view will appear

   _serviceArray = nil;
   self.serviceArray = nil;
2. And also makes sure that the function addService got called: